# .NET Core - cannot find a simple soap request code

Tags: asp.net-core, soap

I need to send an xml like this

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:web="**************">
    <soap:Header/>
    <soap:Body>
        <web:Open>
            <web:username>USERNAME</web:username>
            <web:password>PASSWORD</web:password>
        </web:Open>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

from this tutorial https://stackify.com/soap-net-core/

```
var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
var endpoint = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("http://server/PingService.svc"));
var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory(binding, endpoint);
var serviceClient = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
var result = serviceClient.Ping("Ping");
channelFactory.Close();
```

but how do I modify this code to do my own request ?

I parsed microsoft documentation about WCF and svcutils and it appears infuriatingly complicated
I mean, all that, just to send an XML ?

how to I do a SOAP request **in the simplest manner possible** ?

thanks for helping me on this

Comment: As far as I know, if you want to create a soap request in asp.net core, you should firstly know the SOAP xml request example then you could generate the request. More details, you could refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45055338/7609093).

Comment: I have the soap request, it is posted with the question...I dont see the need of generating anything...I tried in soapui it works fine...I just need a simple SOAP code...which I cannot find anywhere on the web

Comment: I'll check the code you gave, it seems to be what I need, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to import the wsdl from the server side into your project. this will generate most of the required code. An example has been provided in the other question that you asked related to this.

It is also possible to do it completely manually. First you need create one or 2 xml schema's that describe your header and payload (the header is optional).

Open.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:web="http://bvdep.com/webservices/" targetNamespace="http://bvdep.com/webservices/" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:complexType name="OpenType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="username" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="password" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="Open" type="web:OpenType"/>
</xs:schema>
```

header.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:head="http://bvdep.com/webservices/Header" targetNamespace="http://bvdep.com/webservices/Header" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:element name="Header" type="head:HeaderType"/>
    <xs:complexType name="HeaderType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="From" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="To" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="MsgType" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="Datetime" type="xs:dateTime"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

then you use xsd.exe to generate class files. I use a bat file to do so.

```
@echo off
set exepad=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\xsd.exe
set sourcepad=..\..\

set xsdpad=%sourcepad%\ConsoleCore\xsd
set Outpad=%sourcepad%\ConsoleCore\generated

Set NameSpace=ConsoleCore.generated

"%exepad%" "%xsdpad%\Open.xsd" /c  /n:%NameSpace%  /o:%Outpad%
"%exepad%" "%xsdpad%\Header.xsd" /c  /n:%NameSpace%  /o:%Outpad%
```

In your vs core project you need to add 2 nuget packages
System.ServiceModel.Primitives and System.ServiceModel.Http

next you need to add an interface that describes the service an operation(s) that you want to invoke just as you found in the ping example

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://Open.webservice.namespace")]
    public interface IOpenService
    {
        [XmlSerializerFormat()]
        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = false, Action = "urn:#OpenOperation")]
        OpenReturnMsg OpenOperation(OpenMsg msg);
    }

    [MessageContract(IsWrapped = false)]
    public class OpenMsg
    {
        [MessageHeader(Name = "Header", Namespace = "http://bvdep.com/webservices/Header")] public HeaderType Header { get; set; }
        [MessageBodyMember(Name = "Open", Namespace = "http://bvdep.com/webservices/")] public OpenType Open { get; set; }
    }

    [MessageContract(IsWrapped = false)]
    public class OpenReturnMsg
    {
        [MessageBodyMember(Name = "ResponseMsg", Namespace = "http://Open.webservice.namespace")] public string ResponseMsg { get; set; }
    }
```

And last the actual statements to invoke the service and get a response:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Start Program!");

            var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
            var endpoint = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("http://LOCALHOST:8085/mockOpenBinding"));
            var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IOpenService>(binding, endpoint);
            var serviceClient = channelFactory.CreateChannel();


            var msg = new OpenMsg
            {
                Header = new HeaderType
                {
                    From = "source",
                    To = "dest",
                    MsgType = "open",
                    Datetime = DateTime.Now
                },
                Open = new OpenType
                {
                    username = "user",
                    password = "pw"
                }
            };

            var result = serviceClient.OpenOperation(msg);
            channelFactory.Close();
            Console.WriteLine(result.ResponseMsg);
        }
```

i've tested this using a mock service from the below WSDL in SOAPUI.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tns="http://Open.webservice.namespace" xmlns:web="http://bvdep.com/webservices/" xmlns:head="http://bvdep.com/webservices/Header" targetNamespace="http://Open.webservice.namespace">
    <wsdl:types>
        <xs:schema targetNamespace="http://Open.webservice.namespace" elementFormDefault="qualified">
            <xs:import namespace="http://bvdep.com/webservices/Header" schemaLocation="Header.xsd"/>
            <xs:import namespace="http://bvdep.com/webservices/" schemaLocation="Open.xsd"/>
            <xs:element name="ResponseMsg" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="OpenMessageHeader">
        <wsdl:part name="MsgHeader" element="head:Header"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="OpenMessageRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="Open" element="web:Open"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="OpenMessageResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="Response" element="tns:ResponseMsg"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="OpenPortType">
        <wsdl:operation name="OpenOperation">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:OpenMessageRequest"/>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:OpenMessageResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="OpenBinding" type="tns:OpenPortType">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="OpenOperation">
            <soap:operation soapAction="urn:#OpenOperation"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
                <soap:header message="tns:OpenMessageHeader" part="MsgHeader" use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="OpenService">
        <wsdl:port name="OpenPort" binding="tns:OpenBinding">
            <soap:address location="No Target Adress"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```